# ng-click is not firing in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

here is angularJS code:

```
angular.module("app")
.controller("myController", function ($scope) {

    $scope.addDashboard = function() {
        alert('done');
    }
});
```

and here is html code:

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav nav-stacked" id="menu" ng-app="app">

    <li class="dashboard" ng-controller="myController">
        <a id="dashboard_link">
            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
               <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-stack-1x text-success"></i>
            </span>DASHBOARDS   
            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-18" id="test" 
               ng-click="addDashboard()">
            </i>
         </a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

it didn't fire when icon is clicked! any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Check your console for the error. As you didn't initialise the angular module with the empty dependencies, it failed to initialise.

Comment: change module to this `angular.module("app",[])` https://plnkr.co/edit/R4y1KBZ7eQCzV3hdlbED?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Your module should have empty dependency injected,

```
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
```

}

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("myController", function ($scope) {

$scope.addDashboard = function() {
    alert('done');
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="sidebar-nav nav-stacked" id="menu" ng-app="app">

    <li class="dashboard" ng-controller="myController">
        <a  id="dashboard_link"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"   ><i class=" fa-plus fa-stack-18"  ng-click="addDashboard()"></i></span>DASHBOARDS   <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-18" id="test" ng-click="addDashboard()"></i></a>
    </li>
 </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is not mendatory to move  ng-click   out .

Comment: if `app`already registered in project? shall I register it again?

Comment: @Saif Not necessary

Comment: error `Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/ng/areq?p0=myController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined`

Comment: did you refer the controller.js file?

Comment: did it help to sort the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should put     addDashboard mathod in a tag something [like:- This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sw3vcc3m/)

```
<a id="dashboard_link" ng-click="addDashboard()">
```

Your code also working find try to put some sample text in i element on which you put addDashboard method

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.addDashboard = function() {
    alert('done');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<ul class="sidebar-nav nav-stacked" id="menu" ng-app="app">

  <li class="dashboard" ng-controller="myController">
    <a id="dashboard_link">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left">
    <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-stack-1x text-success"></i>
    </span> DASHBOARDS
      <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-18" id="test" ng-click="addDashboard()"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

whether you are using dependency injection or not ,you should implement atleast the empty injection 
`angular.module("app",[])
.controller("myController", function ($scope) {`

Its only the standard syntax for creating global namespace as well as module

Answer (score 0):

First need to understand the difference between **`angular.module('app', [])`** and **`angular.module('app')`**

**angular.module('app', [])**

It will create a new module of the name **`app`**, where the array(**`[]`**) is the set of dependent modules.

**angular.module('app')**

Used to retrieve an existing module of the name **`app`**.

Hence, In your case you have to use `angular.module('app', [])` as you are creating the new module.

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
$scope.addDashboard = function() {
    alert('done');
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-nav nav-stacked" id="menu" ng-app="app">
    <li class="dashboard" ng-controller="myController">
        <a id="dashboard_link" ng-click="addDashboard()"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-stack-1x text-success"></i></span>DASHBOARDS<i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-18" id="test" ></i></a>
    </li>
 </ul>
```